# Finding partial filenames in subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a script where it will go through multiple directories and sub directories and find a matching filename and display it's path.

I was able to do this in shell script with ease and i was able to get the desired output. I have used this in shell like this:

```sh
echo "enter the name of the movie."
read moviename
cd "D:\movies"
find -iname "*$moviename*" > result.txt
cat result.txt
for i in result.txt
do
  if [ "$(stat -c %s "$i")" -le 1 ]
  then
    echo "No such movie exists"
  fi
done
```

This is what I have in python and i'm getting nowhere.

```
import os.path
from os import path

print ('What\'s the name of the movie?')
name = input()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\movies'):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile('D:\movies'+name):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
        else:
            print('No such movie')
```

I want it to search for the filename case insensitive and have it display. I've tried so hard to do it.

Comment: Take a look at [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

name = input('What\'s the name of the movie?')

success = False

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\movies'):
    for file in files:
        if name.lower() in file.lower():
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            success = True
if success == False:
    print('No such movie')
```

You don't need to import each part of os separately.

You can combine input and print into one line.

This is basically asking 'if this string is in that string, print the path'. lower() will make it case insensitive.

I added the success variable as otherwise it will print line for every time a file doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace the (absolutely meaningless, because you don't compare `file` with anything):

```
if os.path.isfile('D:\movies'+name):
```

with:

```
if file.lower().find(name.lower()) != -1 :
```

and have fun with the file list you're getting =)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

MOVIES = Path('D:\movies')

def find_file(name)
    for path in MOVIES.rglob('*'):
        if path.is_file() and name.lower() in path.name.lower():
            break
    else:
        print('File not found.')
        path = None
    return path
```

You could also look into the fuzzywuzzy library for fuzzy matching between file names and input name.